# Detect when osx sleeps / resumes from sleep

Tags: python, c, macos

Is it possible to write a python program (that I will run as a daemon I think) that can detect when osx goes to sleep and also when it resumes from sleep?

Apologies if it sounds like I've not researched this - I'm well out of my comfort zone and unsure if I need to delegate from python to something written in C that can report this, or that's unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's tools to do this in IOKit -- specifically, a callback registered with `IORegisterForSystemPower()` will be called right before the system sleeps, and right after it wakes up.

You may want to check out [bb's `sleepwatcher` daemon](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), which can call commands you specify when a variety of events occur, including system sleep/wake, as well as a variety of other events (display sleep/wake, system idle, shutdown...).

Comment: Cheers - sleepwatcher looks like a very simple solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Cocoa developers can listen for `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification`

```
- (void) receiveSleepNote: (NSNotification*) note
{
    NSLog(@"receiveSleepNote: %@", [note name]);
}

- (void) receiveWakeNote: (NSNotification*) note
{
    NSLog(@"receiveWakeNote: %@", [note name]);
}

- (void) fileNotifications
{
    //These notifications are filed on NSWorkspace's notification center, not the default
    // notification center. You will not receive sleep/wake notifications if you file
    //with the default notification center.
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self
            selector: @selector(receiveSleepNote:)
            name: NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification object: NULL];

    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self
            selector: @selector(receiveWakeNote:)
            name: NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object: NULL];
}
```

This sample code is an excerpt from Apple's documentation here: [Registering and unregistering for sleep and wake notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html)